# Django: Displaying pageviews count in my detail page

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to display the number of times a page have been viewed in my details page. I also want to increment the pageview by 1 anytime the page is anytime the page is loaded. I have a code that does but it also updates my DateTime attribute. How can I achieve this without having to alter everything?

models.py

```
class Music(models.Model):
artist = models.CharField(max_length=300)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(default='', blank=True, unique=True)
thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=False)
audio_file = models.FileField(default='')
uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
description = RichTextUploadingField()
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Meta:
    ordering = ['-uploaded_date']

def save(self):
    self.uploaded_date = timezone.now()
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Music, self).save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title + ' by ' + self.artist

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, slug):
    latest_posts = Music.objects.order_by('-uploaded_date')[:5]
    song = get_object_or_404(Music, slug=slug)
    song.views = song.views + 1
    song.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Sammy, I know you would like to do this yourself but no need to invent the wheel, try https://pypi.org/project/django-visits/ django-visits, I use it all the time with my projects and you can always customise it, makes good use of the cookies, it is great for hat you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

When I *tried* to run the 'pip install django-visits' command, I got the following error

````
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-insta
ll-8t2j3cs9\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__fi
le__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3c
s9\distribute\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\command\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\setuptools\command\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8t2j3cs9\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: I later solved the problem by using easy_install. easy_install Django-visits. But I am having another error here. Can you share a code of how you use it

Comment: visits.Visit.ip_address: (fields.E900) IPAddressField has been removed except for support in historical migrations

Comment: I have the same issue, "IPAddressField has been removed except for support in historical migrations". Did you solve it?